# List sharepoint service account and password update

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Need powershell for listing service account for

- Secure Store Applications
- Search Service Applications
- Web Application Pool

And updating the password for the same. Hope this is as simple as Managed account.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I dont have well dressed code which will do this but rather i have pieces for it.

To get the list of all web application pool.

```
PS C:\Users\prxd3sfa> [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::Conten
tService.ApplicationPools | ft Name , username
```

to get the list of all services application pool's id

```
 Get-SPServiceApplicationPool | ft name, Porcessaccountname
```

Now you have all the services account then you can use the below command to update the password.if you want to use the exiting password

```
$m = Get-SPManagedAccount -Identity “sharepoint\sa-spcontent”

Set-SPManagedAccount -Identity $m  -ExistingPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString “pass@word2″ -AsPlainText -force) –confirm
```

If you want change the password with something new

```
Set-SPManagedAccount -identity Domain\User -NewPassword (Converto-Securestring "P@ssword" -AsPlainText -Force) -SetNewPassword
```